# How can my xmpp app federate with Google Apps users without having them create SRV records?

Tags: xmpp, google-apps

I have an application that uses Prosody and XMPP to communicate with Google Talk users.  I want the app to be able to communicate with Goole Apps users, but according to this document:

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34143

having Google Apps users talk to any xmpp client outside of @gtalk.com requires creating SRV records.

My question is:  How can my app talk to Google Apps users /without/ requiring them to create DNS records for their domain?  (This is highly technical and no one does this.)

Is there some way to trick my server into talking to Google's XMPP server instead of looking for a non-existent XMPP endpoint?

This may require a creative solution.. hosts file, firewalls, special DNS settings... anything?   Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

Have your XMPP server configured to talk to a local DNS server that serves up whatever SRV records you want.  I suggest [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html), with a configuration like this:

```
# Never forward plain names (without a dot or domain part)
domain-needed
# Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces.
bogus-priv

# A SRV record sending XMPP for the example.com domain to
# xmpp-server.l.google.com port 5269

srv-host=_xmpp-server._tcp.example.com,xmpp-server.l.google.com,5269,5
srv-host=_xmpp-server._tcp.example.com,xmpp-server1.l.google.com,5269,20
srv-host=_xmpp-server._tcp.example.com,xmpp-server2.l.google.com,5269,20
srv-host=_xmpp-server._tcp.example.com,xmpp-server3.l.google.com,5269,20
srv-host=_xmpp-server._tcp.example.com,xmpp-server4.l.google.com,5269,20
```

Comment: Even if you do this, it looks like google checks SRV's before communicating externally. http://mail.jabber.org/pipermail/operators/2009-February/000389.html

Comment: Which direction are you communicating?  I thought you had Google Apps for Domains XMPP domains that you wanted to communicate to from a well-known service.  You obviously have to publish SRV domains publicly for your well-known service.

Comment: As of 1/11 my testing indicates that Google does check SRV records externally, or at least setting/spoofing SRV records to send traffic to their XMPP server doesnt result in bi-directional communication.

Comment: @ Joe Hildebrand , my XMPP server is external to Google's.  This allows me to create a lot of jid's without having to create full Google accounts for each.  (The agents are designed to allow mutiple Google Apps user talk to each other in a group.)